# How to convert a readonly git clone from github to a forked one

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-remote

From time to time I encounter this issue.

Let's say that I did following to read the source code of rails because I am running into some issues.

```
git clone git://github.com/rails/rails.git
```

During the research I tested something and now I have a fix I would like rails core team to take a look at. How do I push my changes to a forked version of rails.

Remember when I cloned, I did not clone a forked version but a read-only version.

It is not that I am opposed to forking. It is just that sometimes I think I am just going to browse then I want to add something.

Comment: I'd like to check in and see if my answer works for you, or if you still need more information. If you need further explanation or clarification, let me know, and I can try to help you out. If not, you might want to accept an answer to indicate that the question has been adequately answered.

Answer (score 115):

When you clone a repo, it automatically sets up a remote called `origin` which refers to the repo that you have cloned. This is now pointing to the upstream Rails project, but what you need is to create your own fork that you can push to, and then set up a remote that points there so you can push to it.

The first step is to click the "Fork" button on the upstream GitHub project page (picture from [GitHub instructions on forking](http://help.github.com/forking/)):

[image: GitHub fork button]

Once you've done that, find and copy the URL for that repo. Make sure you use the SSH URL, which has read and write access. It should be something like `git@github.com:nadal/rails.git`, assuming your user name is `nadal`.

Now you can create the remote, which allows Git to keep track of a remote repository, pulling from it or pushing to it depending on the access you have. You can choose to either replace `origin` with the one that you will push to (which is how many people have it set up), or leave `origin` pointing to upstream and instead create a new remote. I'll show how to do the first setup; the second should be easy to figure out.

To change `origin` to point to your fork on GitHub, you will probably want to keep the upstream branch around somewhere, so rename it to `upstream`:

```
git remote rename origin upstream
```

Now create a new remote pointing to your fork:

```
git remote add -f origin git@github.com:nadal/rails.git
```

And now you should be able to push to your new fork:

```
git push origin master
```

Once you are happy with the changes you've pushed up to GitHub, and would like someone from the Rails team to look at it, you have two choices. One is to [send a pull request](http://help.github.com/pull-requests/) using GitHub; see the docs there for how to do that. If you only have one or a few small patches, however, the Rails team would prefer that you [create a Lighthouse ticket](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/sending-patches) and attach you patch; see the instructions on [contributing to Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_rails.html) for more information.

**edit** Here's a diagram to indicate what's going on. What you have done is simply clone the upstream rails repo; so now you have your own repo on your own machine, which refers to `git://github.com/rails/rails.git` as `origin`:

```
Github:    git://github.com/rails/rails.git
                    ^
                    |
Remotes:          origin
                    |
Your machine:     rails/
```

Here's what you get if you forked and then clone your fork:

```
Github:    git://github.com/rails/rails.git <-- git@github.com:nadal/rails.git
                                                           ^
                                                           |
Remotes:                                                origin
                                                           |
Your machine:                                           rails/
```

If you follow my instructions, here is what you will get:

```
Github:    git://github.com/rails/rails.git <-- git@github.com:nadal/rails.git
                        ^                                  ^
                        |                                  |
Remotes:            upstream                            origin
                        |                                  |
Your machine:           \-------------------------------rails/
```

Which is just like the version that you get by forking, except that it also has an `upstream` remote so you can track official changes and merge them in to your code (if you had created the forked version, you would probably want to add the `upstream` remote as well).

Comment: You may not actually want to fork, if as the original poster says, he sometimes may want to save some work instead without any link to the original.

Comment: @adymitruk No, the OP mentioned that he sometimes clones the upstream repo without forking, but then wants to contribute back afterwards. He specifically mentioned that he would like to push his changes to a forked version of Rails. He said nothing about wanting to save work without any link to the original.

Comment: he may want to be a contributor to the actual project then if he does not want to fork... as unlikely as that is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the delay on my part. As I mentioned I did not fork rails. I just have a clone of rails. However your answer assumes that I forked the rails first. Did I get that right?

Comment: @Nadal My answer does not assume that you have already created a fork. My answer explains how to convert a situation in which you've just cloned a repo, into one in which you can push your changes from your local repo into a fork. Forking a repo on GitHub just makes a copy on the server that you can push to; once you've done that, my instructions show you how to point the local repo you've created, which right now points to the official rails repo, to instead point to your fork. I've added a diagram to indicate what's going on; I hope that helps, let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: this was perfect as I ending up needing this exact process.  I cloned a repo for reference, then found I wanted to add something, wasn't sure I could pull it off, so I didn't want to fork to start with.  I was able to accomplish what I wanted but my changes where made against the clone.  Forking after the fact and moving the origin over worked perfectly.  +1

Comment: I'm finding similar information to this. You explain clearly! Now I understand more Github's fork and upstream things. Many thanks! :D

Answer (score 3):

A very easy way to switch from cloned to forked mode is using the `hub` wrapper from http://hub.github.com/.

When this is installed, just run

```
hub fork
```

from within your read-only clone.

Comment: Works nicely. The fork will be created with the same remote name as your github username.

Answer (score 1):

It should not matter. You can add another remote, specifying your non-forked repo, if you so wish. Push your changes to that.

Comment: How do I add another remote. Sorry. newbie to git world.

Comment: you can fork later and then push to your forked repo... in case you haven't forked yet. Forking makes you your own "copy" of the repository you're interested in.

Comment: for now you can just make a new repo on github. Add it as a remote to the one you cloned from the rails repo and push to your new one only. I think this is what you are after. No forking necessary.

Comment: git remote add myrepo git://github.com/myid/mynotforkedrepo.git

Comment: did you create yourself a repo on github (or elsewhere) yet?

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you don't want to fork, and depending on the maintenance team, you can create and submit a patch to them.
Generally though you would make your repo available either by forking on github as explained in other comments, or on your own git repo and provide the maintainers of the original repo with the information to your repo and branch that you want them to merge in.

Comment: I don't understand why one would not want to be forking anyway, since its just a simple fork! Its not a whole new version of the project - just your copy of the source code that you hope is merged in. Just like a patch series.

Comment: Could be that the person doesn't have a Github account but would still like to contribute to the project. They can clone the project, edit and either submit patches or their branch to the original project for inclusion. But true there is no _real_ reason not to fork if you can.