# Already cloned in Git when I should have forked. How do I redo this and push?

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-clone, git-fork

I've been using [The Odin Project](http://www.theodinproject.com/) to teach myself programming.  I thought I figured out Git but I am having a problem with pushing my latest assignment.  When I tried to push it told me access denied because I originally cloned from another persons repo.  I read that in this situation I'm supposed to fork instead of clone.  For the course you're basically supposed to clone the repo and then fix everything and push it to your own.  I don't want to lose anything I completed so I'm not sure what to do next. So far I've

```
-Cloned the repo
-Edited/fixed all the problems etc.
-Saved everything.
-git add -A
-git commit -m
-git push origin master
```

After the push I got the access denied .

Where do I go from here to fork and push all my files to my own repo without screwing everything up?  I've never forked.

Also I'm curious can the Github Windows software be used to do everything you do from the command line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a readonly git clone from github to a forked one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209208/how-to-convert-a-readonly-git-clone-from-github-to-a-forked-one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First start by [forking the original repository on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/#fork-an-example-repository). Then navigate to the fork on GitHub, copy the clone URL and [add it as a remote](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes#Adding-Remote-Repositories) to your repository. You can add the remote by executing `git remote add <remote-name> <clone-url>`. You can choose any name you want for the remote. As an example, I forked the git-scm repository. I could add it as a remote, named `fork`, by executing `git remote add fork git@github.com:dennisschagt/git-scm.com.git`. After adding the remote you can push the commits to your fork with `git push fork master`.

About GitHub for Windows, you can do most regular tasks like creating commits, pushing, pulling, and merging but it has its limitations. For example, this task of adding a new remote is not possible in GitHub for Windows (as far as I know).

Comment: I should have searched first before answering, I believe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4209403/1928529) answers the question in more detail.

Comment: thanks.  I actually ended up backing up the files I added / changed locally and then removed the cloned repo from my git.  Then I forked the repo and cloned again, moved my edited files back to the original folder, and pushed everything.  Seemed to work fine.